# What do the different armor types do?

Tags: droid-assault

Each droid I capture has a unique armor type, such as Kevlar or None. What are the various types, and what advantages do they confer?

Comment: Anyone? Anyone at all?

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.indiefaqs.com/index.php/Droid_Assault_Guide, I could find
5 types of armor.
They are

- None
- Kevlar
- Plasteel
- Titanium
- Nanomesh

Looking online, it seems that the armor is just for show and does not affect the gameplay (It doesn't count towards a health bonus), but I couldn't find a source saying that explicitly.